# latest Angular2 not loading in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, angular, visual-studio-2015

I have created cordova app with Angular2 code and when i deploy the APK in Android. App does't not load anything. It keeps showing loading.... If I run the same angular2 code in browser with angular2 file structure. It works perfect. Angular2 code contain a simple hello world.

When i did the remote debugging for mobile I saw the following error in console.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function(…)consoleError @ zone.js:502

zone.js:504 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function(…)consoleError @ zone.js:504
```

Cordova File Structure...

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular App2</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; 

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './appScripts/app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outDir": "../www/scripts/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser"
  ]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-lectron-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular2 with ElectronPackage",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "author": "na",
  "license": "na",
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings":"^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->

    <script src="js/angularScripts/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularScripts/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularScripts/system.src.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser"></script>-->
    <script src="js/angularScripts/Reflect.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'js/angularScripts/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'scripts',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    //System.import('app/app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    //System.import('app/main').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: I guess you need to install `es6-shim`

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried what you have suggested and still I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?